# Computer will not recognizing 4TB Seagate drive

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, bios, sata

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and this drive will not show up. Occasionally I have managed to fiddle with my BIOS settings to be able to see it in the boot order but in Windows 10 and Ubuntu the drive is not there. On Ubuntu when plugged in I get a bunch of ATA failed errors which I assume is due to the drive being configured improperly.

Not that great at BIOS/Hardware settings so maybe someone can help me figure this out.

- **The Drive:** [Seagate Desktop SSHD ST4000DX001](http://www.seagate.com/internal-hard-drives/solid-state-hybrid/desktop-solid-state-hybrid-drive/) 4TB 64MB Cache SATA 6.0Gb/s 3.5" Solid State Hybrid Drive Bare Drive
- **The Mobo:** [GIGABYTE GA-990FXA-UD3](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3894#ov) AM3+ AMD 990FX + SB950 6 x SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 ATX AMD Motherboard

There are some bad reviews on the drive but it is spinning up but still maybe I need to replace it because it is just crappy?

Comment: You should paste the "ATA failed errors" so that we can see what kind of failures are showing up.  It is possible to [lock a drive so that attempts to use it are rejected with aborted commands](http://www.t13.org/documents/UploadedDocuments/docs2006/e05179r4-ACS-SecurityClarifications.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

According to specs, that motherboard should support 3TB+ HDD's (and hybrid). Whether this includes 4TB+ i have no idea though.

You need to find out what is not working. Try the following steps:

1. Set your BIOS HDD related settings to their default values.
2. Change the SATA cable, its cheap and easy.
3. Plug the drive into a diffrent controller and/or sata port.
4. Move the HDD to another computer to rule out malfunctioning drive.
5. If possible, find another 4TB drive and try that with your motherboard.

By using the above steps you should be able to quickly see which part is not working properly.

Comment: http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3894#ov - 

DualBIOS™ 3TB+ HDD Support (Hybrid EFI Technology)